# LDAP Error: "Server is not operational" from our server

Tags: ldap

I'm having trouble connecting to an Active Directory server from my computer and server.  I get "The server is not operational" error when trying to connect.  The server I'm trying to connect to is in a different country than me.

LDAP Url is in the usual format:
LDAP://***ip_address***:389/CN=Users,DC=***domain_name***,DC=local

I've added the application that connects to the AD to the firewall (even disabled the firewall briefly to test) and added the IP to my hosts file but I can't seem to get past the error.

Now usually at this point, I would conclude that the issue is on the AD server side (or their server firewall) that is blocking requests from our server, however, the person in charge of the AD server has tested the same LDAP url using the same utility I'm using from an external network in their country and is able to authenticate without issues.

Any ideas on what we can try next?

Comment: What is the underlying problem? It should appear somewhere. `No route to host`, for example, or `unreachable`?

Comment: That is the only error I get.  If I do a "telnet ip_address 389", then I get the error:  "Could not open connection to the host, on port 389:  Connection failed"

Comment: Really? `Failed`? or `refused`?

Comment: Failed (via telnet)... I checked the source code as well and there is no innerException.

Comment: Also tried disabling the firewall and anti virus on the AD server for a few seconds to test, but still same error

Comment: We can ping the server from our side, but not connect via Telnet.  Was now in a TeamViewer session with the other person in the other country and we're still clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out the client's ISP was blocking international traffic over port 389.  They had to write a letter to request the ISP to allow international traffic over that port.  It is now working after they've done that.

Didn't know ISPs block traffic, but I suppose ISPs for corporate clients might as in this case.